# What localhost property is guaranteed to be unique across OSes and regardless of network?

Tags: java, networking

Is there a single property concerning a local machine that is guaranteed to be unique on both Windows and OS X regardless of what network they are attached to and is accessible from Java?

For instance, the MAC address returned will change when the active NIC changes (user switches between wired and wireless), hence a MAC address does not meet the criterion.

A hostname is the closest to meeting these criterion:

```
InetAddress localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

hostname = localhost.getHostName();
```

Though in some virtual machine environments where the VM guest is cycled nightly, the hostname can also change (we have such users).

Comment: What exactly do you need here?  Do you actually mean *unique*, or do you mean *unchanging*?  What do you want it for?

Comment: MAC addresses don't change when the user switches networks.  The MAC address is a property of the network hardware, and the wired and wireless interfaces each have their own separate MAC, which is always present regardless of whether that interface is currently "in use".

Comment: I am looking for something that is both unchanging and unique to the local machine.